# Link from FB and Google goes to wrong site

Tags: dns, browsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

If I type http://bharatvinzuda.com in browser I go to the correct site but from elsewhere, for example if I click the link at https://www.google.com/search?q=bharatvinzuda.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a it goes to http://aozpta.mrbonus.com/.

Why can this happen? How can I fix it?

The tags are probably wrong on this question, but I don't know what are the right ones.

EDIT: The result is same if I search at bing or yahoo but duckduckgo takes me to the correct site.

Comment: @RandolphWest where is the virus? You mean on the target machine? There is definitely none on my machines where I see this occurring. If there is a virus on the target machine why would it not intercept in some cases and intercept and divert in other?

Comment: Hemal, I'm sure there's a malware infection on the machine on which you're having redirection issues. Please run through the steps provided on that link, and if the problem persists, then we can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Hmmm. I will run virus checker on that site. He is a friend and a non-tech-savvy user so I won't be surprised if there is *some* malaware on his machine. I will see if fixing that solves the problem